# If $x^p\Bbb{P}(|X|>x)=o(1)$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$ for random variable $X$ and $p>0$, then $\Bbb{E}(|X|^{p-c})<\infty$ for $0<c<p$.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integration

The problem is:

> If $x^p\Bbb{P}(|X|>x)=o(1)$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$ for random variable $X$ and $p>0$, then $\Bbb{E}(|X|^{p-c})<\infty$ for $0<c<p$.

my attempt is:

Let $x=n$, then 
$$n^{p-c}\Bbb{P}(|X|>n)=o(n^{-c}) $$
and
$$\Bbb{E}(|X|^{p-c})\leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}[(n+1)^{p-c}-n^{p-c}]\Bbb{P}(|X|\geq n)$$
when $n$ is large enough, we have $(n+1)^{p-c}-n^{p-c}<2(p-c)n^{p-c-1}$, without loss of generality, assume it holds for all $n$, so 
$$\Bbb{E}(|X|^{p-c})\leq 2(p-c)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n^{p-c-1}\Bbb{P}(|X|\geq n)=2(p-c)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}o(n^{-c-1})<\infty$$

my question is :

1. Is the proof correct?
2. For $c=0$ we showed that $\Bbb{E}(|X|^p)\leq 2p\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}o(n^{-1})$, but it may be infinite, such as $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(n\log n)^{-1}$. So could you give me a counterexample for $c=0$?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For any nonnegative RV $Y$, 
   $$E[ Y ] = \int_0^\infty P(Y>y) dy.$$
2. As a result, for any $r> 0$,

$$(*) \quad E[|X|^r] = \int_0^\infty P(|X|^r>z) dz \overset{z=x^r}{=} r \int_0^\infty P(|X|>x)x^{r-1} dx.$$

Note that if the RHS is infinite, it is because of tail behavior, not behavior near zero, because $r>0$. Keep this in mind for the next item.

3. Let $p>0$. Then

$$E[|X|^r] = r \int_0^\infty  x^p P(|X|>x) x^{r-p-1} dx.$$

Thus, if

$$\limsup_{x\to\infty} x^p P(|X|>x)<\infty,$$

then

$$E[|X|^r]<\infty \mbox{ for all }0<r<p.$$

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample for $c=0$: let $X$ have density $f(x)=-\frac d  {dx} \frac c {x(log\, x)}$ on $(1,\infty)$, with $f(x)=0$ for $x \leq 1$. (Choose $c$ so that the function integrates to $1$).  Then the hypothesis holds with $p=1$ but $EX=\infty$.